# Pass environment created in codebuild action to downstream action in codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, xcodebuild, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I'm new to codepipeline & I have multiple actions in a build stage in codepipeline, which 1 buildspec similar to below , and i want to dynamically create a variable here in the python file which i need for a downstream action.

```
version: 1
phases:
  install:
    runtime-version:
      python: 3.9
    commands:
      - python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
  build:
    commands:
      - python code/get_date.py
```

get_date.py

```
import datetime
if __name__ == "__main__":
    current_date = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
```

Then I have a second buildspec file which runs in the second action

```
version: 1
phases:
  install:
    runtime-version:
      python: 3.9
    commands:
      - python -m pip install --upgrade pip 
  build:
    commands:
      - python code/process_date.py
```

process_date.py

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # get current date somehow from previous action
    print(current_date)
```

How do I accomplish something like this? And what is the best recommendation? Would i use output artifacts or variables? And how are they used to pass values like this between stages?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodeBuild can output variables to be used in other stages or actions in your CodePipeline. These variables are called [CodeBuild action output variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html#reference-variables-list-configured-codebuild) and are defined using [env/exported-variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec.env.exported-variables) in your `buildspec.yml`.

General info how to consume and use these variables in a CP are described in [Working with variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html) AWS docs.

Comment: How do these variables get created for export in the python script in codebuild? Do i need to do anything to write to an environment variable?

Comment: @ersh Did you read the docs? It explains you have to define them.